# Adding to a JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a JSON string as follows:

```
[
    {"TypeName":"Double","TypeID":14},
    {"TypeName":"Single","TypeID":43},
    {"TypeName":"Family","TypeID":7}
]
```

It is generated after calling this function in KnockOut:

```
self.save = function() {
    var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function(line) {
        return line.product() ? {
            TypeName: line.category().TypeName,
            TypeID: line.category().TypeID
            : undefined
});

alert(JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
```

However, I want to add 3 more pieces of information to the model, before posting it back to my server - to also send Name, Email and Tel:

```
{
    "Name":"Mark",
    "Email":"me@me.com",
    "Tel":"0123456789",
    "Rooms":
        [
            {"TypeName":"Double","TypeID":14},
            {"TypeName":"Single","TypeID":43},
            {"TypeName":"Family","TypeID":7}
        ]
}
```

Is there a proper way of adding this information to the JSON, or is it just as simple as:

```
var toSend = "{\"Name\":\"Mark\":\"Email\":\"me@me.com\", \"Tel\":\"0123456789\",\"Rooms\":"
+ JSON.stringify(dataToSave) + "}";
```

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: I would parse and stringify. Perhaps leave out parsing if possible altogether. Your code seems it should work - learn to love the single quotes though, so that you don't have to escape as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse your JSON string using `JSON.parse` into a valid JS object, add the data to the object as needed, then `JSON.stringify` it back. A JSON string is just a representation of your data, so you shouldn't rely on modifying it directly.

Comment: `+1` - This is the only way to guarantee the JSON stays valid.

Comment: This is good advice if you don't have control over the data until after it has been encoded, but that's not the case here.  He can simply pass a different structure to the JSON encoder.

Answer (score 3):

Why encode to JSON and then modify the resulting string when you can pass the structure you *actually* want to the JSON encdoder?

```
var toSend = JSON.stringify({
    Name: "Mark",
    Email: "me@me.com",
    Tel: "0123456789",
    Rooms: dataToSave
});
```